# Media Query not working for Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to implement a media query for my samsung  galaxy note 8. Somehow i managed to implement for my S4 as shown below.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 440px)
```

This works because S4's ppi is 441px. As for note 8, it's ppi is 189. Therefore i used this media query

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 189px)
```

as note8's ppi is 189. However, the css i insert inside the 189px does not apply for my note 8.

Does anyone have any idea why does the note 8 not detect this ppi?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using device-pixel-ratio:2, coz of the screen resolution the styles wont reflect..

```
  @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and ( -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and ( min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and ( min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and ( min-resolution: 2dppx) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to get device's width in `px` since your media query is in `px`.

Change

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 440px)` to

`@media ( min-width :481px) and ( max-width :767px)`

also try **decreasing** `min-width` & simultaneously **increase** `max-width` to see where your device lies.

Visit any of these sites from your device and get all relevant info, then find out what is going wrong.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/mediaqueries/devicewidth.html

http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/

Comment: Tried and unfortunately all these methods doesn't work.